# How good is this cipher? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a cipher on python and I want to know how good it is, I calculated there are about 10^1025 possibilities for the key, is that any good? I can easily make it bigger. I mainly focused on the 'hard encoding' by the way.

Here is the code:

```
import random
import itertools
print ('''
         READ THIS BEFORE USE

    This encryption can ONLY use ASCII
    this contains most/all of the 
    keys on your keyboard, this
    includes capital letters

    The key supports around 100000 digits.

    The hard encoding adds three more
    layers of security. You will have to
    copy your new key.
    x
    by Tudor Popescu
    ''')

    hard_encoding_1 = {
'0': '8',
'1': '4',
'2': '3',
'3': '7',
'4': '1',
'5': '9',
'6': '5',
'7': '6',
'8': '2',
'9': '0',
}

hard_encoding_2 = {
'0': '5',
'1': '9',
'2': '0',
'3': '1',
'4': '4',
'5': '3',
'6': '7',
'7': '2',
'8': '6',
'9': '8',
}

hard_encoding_3 = {
'0': '2',
'1': '5',
'2': '7',
'3': '4',
'4': '9',
'5': '8',
'6': '1',
'7': '0',
'8': '3',
'9': '6',
}

hard_encoding_4 = {
'0': '1',
'1': '3',
'2': '5',
'3': '8',
'4': '0',
'5': '7',
'6': '6',
'7': '2',
'8': '9',
'9': '4',
}


def randint_generator(n):
    key_generate = ''
    for b in range(n):
        b = random.randint(0, 9)
        key_generate = key_generate + str(b)
    return 'copy this key: ' + key_generate


def randint_generator_nonreturn(n):
    key_generate = ''
    for b in range(n):
        b = random.randint(0, 9)
        key_generate = key_generate + str(b)
    return key_generate


def setnumber(x, y, str_or_int):
    n = len(str(x))
    z = str(x)
    while n != y:
        z = '0' + z
        n = len(z)
    if str_or_int == str:
    return str(z)
if str_or_int == int:
    return int(z)


while True:
    What_operation = int(input('''
    Do you want to:
            soft:
            decrypt(0)
            encrypt(1)
        hard:
            decrypt(3)
            encrypt(4)
        generate a key:
            100-digit(5)
            500-digit(6)
            1,000-digit(7)
            10,000-digit(8)
            1,000,000-digit(9)
            '''))


if What_operation == 1:
    text = input('What is your text you want to convert? ')
    New_text = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(), 'big'))
    key = int(input('What is your key you want to use?'))
    cyphered_text = int(New_text[2:]) * key
    print ('copy this text: ', cyphered_text)

if What_operation == 0:
    try:
        numbers = input('What is your string you want to convert? ')
        key = int(input('What is your key? '))
        New_text = '0b' + str(int(numbers) // key)
        encoded = int(New_text,2)
        decoded = encoded.to_bytes((encoded.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 
        'big').decode()
        print ('Here is your message: ' + decoded)
    except ValueError:
        print('Your key or/and encrypted text are incorrect! ')

if What_operation == 4:
    try:
        text = input('What is your text you want to convert? ')
        New_text = bin(int.from_bytes(text.encode(), 'big'))
        key = int(randint_generator_nonreturn(1000))
        key_2 = random.randint(1,4)
        cyphered_text = New_text[2:]
        hard_cyphered_text = ''
        cyphered_text = int(cyphered_text) * key
        for i in str(cyphered_text):
            if key_2 == 1:
                hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_1[i]
            if key_2 == 2:
                hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_2[i]
            if key_2 == 3:
                hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_3[i]
            if key_2 == 4:
                hard_cyphered_text = hard_cyphered_text + hard_encoding_4[i]
        x_cyphered_text = str(hard_cyphered_text)
        array0, array1, array2 = '', '', ''
        count = 0
        for i in x_cyphered_text:
            if count % 3 == 0:
                array0 += i
            count += 1
        count = 0
        for i in x_cyphered_text:
            if count % 3 == 1:
                array1 += i
            count += 1
        count = 0
        for i in x_cyphered_text:
            if count % 3 == 2:
                array2 += i
            count += 1
        array0_key, array1_key, array2_key = random.randint(1, 99999999), 
        random.randint(1, 99999999), random.randint(1, 99999999)
        final_array0, final_array1, final_array2 = int(array0) * array0_key, 
        int(array1) * array1_key, int(array2) * array2_key
        len_array0, len_array1, len_array2 = str(len(str(final_array0))), 
        str(len(str(final_array1))), str(len(str(final_array2)))
        full_key = str(key) + str(key_2) + setnumber(len_array0, 6, str) + 
        setnumber(len_array1, 6, str) + setnumber(len_array2, 6, str) + 
        setnumber(array0_key, 8, str) + setnumber(array1_key, 8, str) + 
        setnumber(array2_key, 8, str)
        complete_cyphered_text = str(final_array0) + str(final_array1) + 
        str(final_array2)
        print('copy this text: ', complete_cyphered_text)
        print('Copy your key: ', full_key)
    except ValueError:
        print('You aren\'t using ASCII or you copied a text with 
        paragraphs')

if What_operation == 3:
    try:
        numbers = input('What is your string you want to convert? ')
        key = input('What is your given key? ')
        key_2 = int(key[-43:-42])
        array2_key, array1_key, array0_key = int(key[-8:]), 
        int(key[-16:-8]), int(key[-24:-16])
        len_array2, len_array1, len_array0 = int(key[-30:-24]), 
        int(key[-36:-30]), int(key[-42:-36])
        n0, n1, n2 = len_array0, len_array1, len_array2
        crypt_array0, crypt_array1, crypt_array2 = numbers[:n0], 
        numbers[n0:n0 + n1], numbers[n0 + n1:]
        array0, array1, array2 = (int(crypt_array0) // array0_key), 
        (int(crypt_array1) // array1_key), (int(crypt_array2) // array2_key)
        numbers_noncrypt = ''.join(''.join(x) for x in 
        itertools.zip_longest(str(array0), str(array1), str(array2), 
        fillvalue=''))
        key = int(str(key)[:-43])
        encoded_text = ''
        decoding = {}
        if key_2 == 1:
            decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_1.items()}
        if key_2 == 2:
            decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_2.items()}
        if key_2 == 3:
            decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_3.items()}
        if key_2 == 4:
            decoding = {a: b for b, a in hard_encoding_4.items()}
        for i in str(numbers_noncrypt):
            encoded_text = encoded_text + decoding[i]
        encoded_text = '0b' + str(int(encoded_text) // key)
        encoded = int(encoded_text, 2)
        decoded = encoded.to_bytes((encoded.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 
        'big').decode()
        print ('Here is your message: ' + decoded)
    except ValueError:
        print('Your key or/and encrypted text are incorrect! ')

if What_operation == 5:
    print(randint_generator(100))
if What_operation == 6:
    print(randint_generator(500))
if What_operation == 7:
    print(randint_generator(1000))
if What_operation == 8:
    print(randint_generator(10000))
if What_operation == 9:
    print(randint_generator(1000000))
```

Comment: @Coal_ I have put the code in the review

Comment: @Josiah I have put the code in the review

Comment: Please fix your indentation. The easiest way to post code is to paste it into the question editor, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to mark it as a code block.

Comment: "is that any good" to do what?

Comment: @Mast if it is a secure cipher and not easily breakable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should start off by saying, as a standard disclaimer, that cryptography experts consistently recommend that the best way to implement a secure cipher is to let someone else do it! That's not to say don't have a go for a bit of fun or as a learning experience. (I decided to invent one myself back when I was 14 or so. It wasn't very good, but it was a good place to start.) I would just say that if you're using cryptography for real to run an online bank or something, then use a standard library implementation of a standard cipher.

Here's a few of the common pitfalls that everyone falls into if they're not university professor level experts.

1. Key generation has to be really random. Most ways that computers generate random numbers aren't very random. They just run some numbers through a complicated formula that is too chaotic for humans to track, but if you know just a little bit about what the formula started with you can predict the numbers it will produce with perfect accuracy. For example, this is what the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html) say about the inbuilt random module:

> Python uses the Mersenne Twister as the core generator. It produces
>   53-bit precision floats and has a period of 2**19937-1. The underlying
>   implementation in C is both fast and threadsafe. The Mersenne Twister
>   is one of the most extensively tested random number generators in
>   existence. However, being completely deterministic, it is not suitable
>   for all purposes, and is completely unsuitable for cryptographic
>   purposes.

2. A secure encryption program should be secure against an enemy who plays dirty. There are tricks that someone who is trying to break a cipher can do. For example, if the computer starts to run out of RAM it will write some of the things it needs to remember to the hard disk. If the cipher program isn't careful, that might include the key. Then the bad guy can just read that bit of the hard disk for anything that looks like a key.
   Other tricks include measuring how long a computer takes to encrypt something, or even leaving a microphone in the room with the computer and listening to the noises it makes as it works. This is because some algorithms take longer or make more noise when processing some bits of a key than others. Writing a cipher to be secure against a dirty fighting adversary involves thinking about exactly what a CPU does with each instruction. (I would go so far as to say that for this sort of level, it's impossible to write a completly secure cipher against this sort of attacker in Python, because Python lets you tell the computer what to do but not exactly how to do it.)
3. A secure encryption program should be secure even against someone who knows what some of your messages say, and uses that to help them work out the ones they don't know. You might think that's a silly requirement: they don't know what the message says because it's encrypted with the cipher! But this was actually really relevant in history, in the British codebreaking effort in the Second World War. The British knew that at a certain time the U-boat commanders would send a weather report to the rest of the navy (and the British could guess what the report said by checking the weather!) and they knew that the Nazis would sign off their messages with "Hail Hitler". They could use that to work out what other more important messages encrypted with the "unbreakable" Enigma machine said.

Anyway, like I said it's fine to have a go. This was just a quick primer to explain how hard it is to beat the best cryptanalysts (People who try to break ciphers).

---

Looking specifically at your code and your cipher

Your `hard_encoding_x` set up is a standard substitution cipher with, essentially, a fixed key. You should always assume in cryptography that the enemy knows everything about the system: basically assume they have your source code. The only thing you can assume they don't have is secret keys, which in this case is which of the four substitution tables you used. So, that does, hopefully, make it 4 times harder to decrypt, but not more than that. You could make things better by generating the tables as part of your key, but do note that [frequency analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis) is notoriously effective against substitution ciphers.

The more fundamental bit of your basic cipher is multiplying by a really huge random number. You're right that, all things being equal, bigger keys help security. And you do have a lot of possible keys! If I was a cryptanalyst trying to break your cipher, I would be looking for ways to avoid needing to check all the possible keys.

One thing that I might try is guessing what your message says. Suppose I know that you've sent a message that either says "attack" or "retreat", but I don't know which. With a good cipher, I can't tell even with the encrypted message, unless I have the key. That is because under some key, "attack" would give this encrypted message and under another key "retreat" would. However with multiplication, I have a way in. What I have to do is check whether the ciphertext is a multiple of the number representation of "attack" and whether it has a remainder when divided by the number representation of "defend".

It's a useful and fun skill whenever you make something that is meant to be safe, to immediately turn around and imagine you're the bad guy, who knows as much as you do about the system you just made, and work out ways it might still be attacked. (Although of course not seeing any ways doesn't mean they aren't there. But if you can see them, you can fix them!)
So, as a fun exercise, suppose that you can't possibly guess the message, but you get a dozen different messages all multiplied by the same key. What mathematical property of the dozen encryped messages would probably allow you to work out the key?

I will say that the process you go through to split up the message into thirds probably does frustrate simple attacks like this one. It's 2 A.M. here and my brain is not engaged enough to come up with exactly how I'd go about attacking that component of the cipher, but hopefully I've given you enough to think about.

---

Finally, you asked about how secure the cipher is, but while I'm here I might as well make a few suggestions about general coding style.

Firstly, using Python 3 is a big plus! An annoyingly large number of people still insist on using the old Python 2, and it's generally good to use the newest versions of technology if possible.

It would help to have a few more comments dotted around. In particular, all your lines `if What_operation == ...` should be followed by a comment to remind the reader what the number corresponds to. Likewise, it would be helpful to have comments explaining what your functions are meant to do and what your variables are meant to represent.

If you find yourself repeating yourself, look for ways to use arrays and loops. For example, instead of

```
array0_key, array1_key, array2_key = random.randint(1, 99999999), random.randint(1, 99999999), random.randint(1, 99999999)
```

You could have

```
array_keys=[]
for i in range(3):
    array_keys[i] = random.randint(1, 99999999)
```

Oh, and as mentioned at the top, avoid Python's `random` if you want anything security related. Instead use the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module. Something like `b = secrets.randbelow(10)`

Comment: That was a very in depth answer, as you could tell my code was not that complicated as I am only 14 yrs old, and this was an assignment that I had to do. But I will implement what you said - having a much bigger first key, having the substitution in the key, doing a secret randomisation etc. What you said was very helpful for me and I will follow on from it. Do you think I should use the substitution with other characters (eg. #$&)? Thanks again

Comment: Yeah, I would suggest that a substitution cipher is a good choice for a crypto project. I would suggest making a version that just does substitution (but generates the substitution table randomly). 

If you fancy making a "hard encoding" option for that, look at the wikipedia page on frequency analysis, which mentions some of the tricks people have used in history to make substitution ciphers more secure. (One, called polyalphabetic ciphers, is basically the same trick as you came up with for splitting the message into 3 bits and encrypting each one separately)

Comment: I will implement what you said and I will edit the question with the new code. I will read the frequency analysis article to use it.

Comment: The practice on this site is to have a new question when you change the code, just to help stop things getting confusing in terms of what reviews refer to what versions of the code.

Comment: I will keep that in mind, I'll post a new question when I have finished it